# Need regex help - How to extract a String using regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for regex to extract a string from another string.

```
"sasl.jaas.config=com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule REQUIRED 
storeKey=true principal='test@test.net' validate=true serviceName=esaas 
keyTab='<some value>' useKeyTab=true;"
```

How to I extract the string after keyTab= I want to retrieve the value inside the single quotes -

Comment: Regex is used in many different programming languages and tools. And there are different flavors of regex. So in what would you use the regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regex **keyTab='(.*?)'** and match the group 1. In java, your code should look like this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String content = "\"sasl.jaas.config=com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule REQUIRED \r\n" + 
            "storeKey=true principal='test@test.net' validate=true serviceName=esaas \r\n" + 
            "keyTab='<some value>' useKeyTab=true;\"";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("keyTab='(.*?)'");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
        matcher.find();
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); //<some value>
    }
}
```

Comment: @s_bighead Regarding your suggested edit, did the OP say he's using Java?

Comment: Actually no, but I could infer that by the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Something that will work in most regex engine is to look for both the thing you want and the thing before it.
And put the thing you want in a capture group

This regex will put what's between the quotes in capture group `\1`

```
\bkeyTab=\'([^\']*)\'
```

The `\b` is a word boundary to make sure keyTab isn't part of a larger word.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason that your capture group is `[^']` instead of `(.*?)`? It's far more common to see the latter when extracting text between quotes, so long as the capture group is followed by a quote.

Comment: There's also one "problem" with `[^']`, that is, it will match EOL characters, which _in most cases_ isn't the desired behavior.

Comment: It's one of the regex tricks. And it's often faster in large strings. I think it's because it causes less backtracking compared to the lazy search.

Comment: Well, it's fine if your using it for code generated text. Because then a starting quote is kinda garanteed to have an ending quote. Based on his sample text I believe this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression to find it:

```
keyTab='(.*?)'
```

It will find all the values around `keyTab='...'`, but will only capture what is between the quotes.

Comment: Thank you. this one grabs the complete key value keyTab='<some value>'. Is there a way to extract just the value which is <some value>?

Comment: @Srinivas While the regular expression _matches_ the whole "keyTab..." string, it will only _capture_ the text between the quotes (<some value>). As LukStorms' answer explains, the value is stored in capture group `\1`. Which programming language are you utilizing this regex in? The way to extract the capture group will depend on which language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```
[\n\r].*keyTab='\s*([^\n\r]*)'
```

Your desired match will be in capture group 1.

Comment: Why do you need to match `[\n\r]` before and exclude it  in the capture group?

Comment: A few minor considerations: Be careful with the `\n\r`. *nix generally uses `\n`, while windows uses `\r\n`, and a generated file could use whichever characters in which ever order they want. You could simply use Regex's `^` character to represent the start of a line. Although, since you follow the start of the line with `.*`, there probably isn't a need to check for the start of a new line at all. Additionally, the "zero+ matches" (`*`) is greedy, and will continue to capture everything up until the final closing quote character. If there were any additional attributes, this might not work.

Comment: Yes, you are right about '. It works only if there are two quotes.